# Is this sentence correct? And why? (Answered)

Tags: grammar, past-participles, present-continuous

So I was reading a novel (I'm not a native) and I found a sentence that goes like "its branches spreading up to the sky..."

Why there is no "were" or "are" after the word "branches"? Isn't that supposed to be a present/past continues?

Comment: It's a bit poetic but normal. Think of spreading as a modifier: The cat napping, the dough rising till doubled, a ballerina doing her turns, its branches leafing out in Spring.

Comment: Are you sure that was used as standalone sentence? If it were, for example, *The tree was lovely, its branches spreading up to the sky*, then *its branches spreading up to the sky* is known as an absolute phrase.

Comment: If that's what you found, verbatim, stop reading that book. That's not a sentence at all.

Comment: Oh sorry. I should've included the whole thing. There's a sentence before that phrase (now i know that's phrase). Thanks for the answers guys! It's completely cleared thing up :)

Comment: The full sentence seems to be "A magnificent cherry tree in full bloom filled the horizon, its branches spreading up to the sky"